Don't understand why string line don't get data from file
Trying to make a code, that will create a array of structures "simulating" a card whith to fields kind and size, write down this fields into txt file and fullfill another array of cards with data from that txt file
#include "deck.cpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    const int size = 36;
    deck col[size];
    char kind[4][13] = {"пики", "буби", "крести", "черви"};

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        col[i].kind = kind[rand()%4];
        col[i].size = rand() % 13 + 2;
    }

    ofstream out;
    out.open("deck.txt");
    out.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        out << col[i].kind+"\n" << to_string(col[i].size)+"\n";
    }

    deck sol[size]; 

    string line;
    ifstream in("deck.txt");
    int i = 0;
    while (getline(in, line, '\n')) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            sol[i / 2].kind = line;
        }
        else {
            sol[(i - 1) / 2].size = stoi(line);
        }
        i++;
    }

}

evrything works "fine" until it's time to take data from file. while block ignores/ i tried changing way of inputing data, even tried use excel insted of txt, but still i didn't get where i mistaked

Immediate issues that jump out at me: including a ".cpp" file is wrong. You have VLAs deck col[size]; which are not a standard part of C++ (use std::vector instead), and you've included <string> but you're using C-style char arrays.

@Chris deck col[size] is not a VLA.

@Liron How do you execute your code? Are you sure your current working directory is the same directory that contains deck.txt?

#include "deck.cpp" is not a good idea. You include header files, and build source files.

As for your problem, try closing the output file stream before you try to read from the same file. It might not have been properly flushed otherwise.

@Yksisarvinen thanks. I missed that. Though probably better constexpr std::size_t size = 36;

Oh, and out << col[i].kind+"\n" << to_string(col[i].size)+"\n"; won't do what you think it does. Why do you add the newline? Shouldn't you be outputting it instead, using the stream output operator <<? And there's no need for the to_string call either. Please take some time to refresh the chapters about stream output, to std::cout or to files, in your beginners learning material.

I understand that including cpp files is bad and i know that to do with it. deck.txt is in the same folder as solution.

For your reading, read two lines at once, instead of one line and then use arithmetic to decide which line it is. And I suggest you take some time to create overloaded stream input and output operators >> and << for your deck class. And even though this simple test program you show should work, if the output file was created, you should always check for errors, and make sure that the files (both for output and input) really are opened successfully.

everyone else, thanks for advices

It sounds like it would have been useful to check the contents of deck.txt and maybe to post them here. If the problem is now resolved, could you please either add an answer that contrasts the erroneous std::cout << type + "\n" with the correct std::cout << type << "\n", or flag the question for deletion.
